# How to change base URL and enable prettyUrl in yii2

Tags: yii2

How can I change my base url : `http://mydomin/ProjectName/frontend/web/index.php?r=product/index` to something like this `http://mydomin/product/index`? I read many articles about this topic but none of it proof useful. I also tried the following:

(1) enable prettyUrl in my config file at frontend/config/main.php and I added some rules as I read from an article..

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'product/<controller:\w+>/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'product/<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

(2) I created a .htaccess file at my web directory at /frontend/web/.htaccess and I added the below code:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Now, when I try to access `http://mydomin/ProjectName/frontend/web/product/index`
I got error message: The requested URL `/ProjectName/frontend/web/product` was not found on this server. if I comment out `'showScriptName' => false`, in the urlManager setting  it works in this format `http://mydomin/ProjectName/frontend/web/index.php/product/index`
it stripe off the `?r=` but still have the `index.php` file..
how can I do it to hide this file and even hide all app folder like `projectName, frontend,and web folder` so at the end instead of `http://mydomin/ProjectName/frontend/web/index.php/product/index` or `http://mydomin/ProjectName/frontend/web/index.php?r=product/index` I will just  get `http://mydomin/product/index`

Answer (score 1):

1- put this code in .htaccess flie in yii2advance folder (main folder of project)

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1
```

above code convert

```
'localhost/yii2advance/frontend/web/index.php'
```

to

```
'localhost/yii2advance/'
```

and it convert

```
'localhost/yii2advance/backend/web/index.php'
```

to

```
'localhost/yii2advance/admin'
```

2- add this code to frontend/.htaccess and backend/.htaccess file:
RewriteEngine on

```
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

3- in backend/config/main.php put this codes:

```
'homeUrl' => '/yii2advance/admin',

'components' => [
'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/yii2advance/admin', // localhost/yii2advance/admin
        ],
    'urlManager' => [
         'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
         'showScriptName' => false,
         'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ],
],
```

4- in frontend/config/main.php put this codes:

```
'homeUrl' => '/yii2advance',

'components' => [
'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => '/yii2advance', // localhost/yii2advance
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
         'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
         'showScriptName' => false,
         'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ],
],
```

Comment: i tried this code as stated above and it's not working am getting 404 error when trying to access  baseUrl i.e /yii2advance/admin, pls what am i missing out, do i have to make any changes to my apache server to make this work??

Comment: is your project on localhost or you uploaded it?

Comment: my project is on local host

Comment: You should put your project root folder instead yii2advance,

Comment: I think you changed your apache config

Comment: you don't need to chang your apache config, i used above code many times and it worked correctly

Comment: the 'homeUrl' => '/yii2advance', and the 'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => '/yii2advance', // localhost/yii2advance
    ], are they in components array or outside it, you place it outside why someelse place it inside, though i try both none work still and no error message on both try, so am not sure where to place it

Comment: 'homeUrl' is  out of components and 'request' is inside of components

Comment: which question would it be then?

Answer (score 0):

If you use advanced-yii2 template, you must create virtual host for yor apache, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName yourlocalhost.ru

    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourlocalproject/frontend/web
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/yourlocalproject/frontend/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**yourlocalhost.ru** - Your local hostname
**yourlocalproject** - yii project directory

And don't forget add yourlocalhost.ru to hosts file and restart apache